# My observable array is not updating, am I doing this correctly?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

```
function AppViewModel() {
self.tagbuttons=ko.observableArray([
    {shotbar:false, frozendrinks: false, livemusic: false, patio:false, food:false}
    ]);

self.toggleTag = function(data,event) {
    var id = event.target.id;

    self.tagbuttons()[0][id] = !self.tagbuttons()[0][id];
    console.log(self.tagbuttons()[0][id]);
    if(self.tagbuttons()[0][id] == true)
    {
        $(event.target).closest('li').addClass("active");
        console.log(event.target.id+":"+"active");
    }
    else
    {
        $(event.target).closest('li').removeClass("active");
        console.log(event.target.id+":"+"inactive");}
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

My console.log(self.tagbuttons()[0][id]) outputs the correct bool value, but the value does not update in my array. Here is my html:

```
 <div data-bind="text: tagbuttons()[0].shotbar"></di>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the KO bindings after you declare your MyAppViewModel and after the UI is loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    ko.ApplyBindings(new MyAppViewModel())?  
});
```

Unless you are applying the KO bindings, nothing will happen outside of the view model.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quote from the ko documentation:

> **Key point: An observableArray tracks which objects are in the array, not the state of those objects**
>
> Simply putting an object into an observableArray doesn’t make all
>   of that object’s properties themselves observable. Of course, you can
>   make those properties observable if you wish, but that’s an
>   independent choice. An observableArray just tracks which objects it
>   holds, and notifies listeners when objects are added or removed.

So when you are changing array item's value knockout is not notified. You can use `valueHasMutated` function to notify subscribers manually:

```
self.tagbuttons()[0][id] = !self.tagbuttons()[0][id];
self.tagbuttons.valueHasMutated();
```

Or wrap items in array with `observalbe`:

```
self.tagbuttons = ko.observableArray([
ko.observable({
    shotbar:false, 
    frozendrinks: false, 
    livemusic: false, 
    patio:false, 
    food:false})
    ]);
```